# Docker where is file to run?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I got a project with a dockerfile, I installed docker and (after seraching to find I need a '.' at the end cause iwas running it without) I run

```
docker build -t sometag .
```

and it seems to build but when I do 
docker image ls, I get:

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              5933185d4f8d        About an hour ago   68.1MB
hello-world         latest              4ab4c602aa5e        2 months ago        1.84kB
node                8.10-alpine         adc4b0f5bc53        8 months ago        68.1MB
```

I thought my image was supposed to be there so i could run it but I dont see it there, and if I type

```
docker run sometag
```

it doesnt find it.
And i also tried running the first one via its id since that is when i started building images but might have not used a tag so though maybe it was the first one and did

```
docker run 5933185d4f8d
```

but it just returns me to the console

I do see now that it never gets past step 5/8, it prints like a whole help section and ends saying

```
This apk has coffee making abilities.
The command '/bin/sh -c apk install git   && npm i   && apk del .gyp  && mv /var/app/node_modules /node_modules   && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*   && apk del git' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.10-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV development

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /var/app

# Install Node packages
COPY package.json package.json

RUN apk install git \
  && npm i \
  && apk del .gyp\
  && mv /var/app/node_modules /node_modules \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
  && apk del git

# Bundle app source
COPY . .
#COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh

# Expose port
EXPOSE 88

#ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

This is what I get when I remove the git lines:

```
$ docker build -t swipeimage .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  185.6MB
[WARNING]: Empty continuation line found in:
    RUN  npm i   && apk del .gyp  && mv /var/app/node_modules /node_modules   && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* COPY . .
[WARNING]: Empty continuation lines will become errors in a future release.
Step 1/7 : FROM node:8.10-alpine
 ---> adc4b0f5bc53
Step 2/7 : ENV NODE_ENV development
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 125f132ddd28
Step 3/7 : WORKDIR /var/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f4382f4d2a0b
Step 4/7 : COPY package.json package.json
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5933185d4f8d
Step 5/7 : RUN  npm i   && apk del .gyp  && mv /var/app/node_modules /node_modules   && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* COPY . .
 ---> Running in 4ee9c07920ca
npm WARN deprecated bcrypt@1.0.3: bcrypt < v2.0.0 is susceptible to bcrypt wrap-around bug. Upgrade to bcrypt >= v2.0.0 for improved support for newer bcrypt hashes
npm WARN deprecated nsp@3.2.1: The Node Security Platform service is shutting down 9/30 - https://blog.npmjs.org/post/175511531085/the-node-security-platform-service-is-shutting
npm WARN deprecated sendgrid@4.10.0: Please see v6.X+ at https://www.npmjs.com/org/sendgrid
npm WARN deprecated supertest-as-promised@4.0.2: SuperTest 2.0+ supports promises natively; use that instead!
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] debug has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=debug&version=2.6.8 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] superagent has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=superagent&version=1.8.5 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] superagent has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=superagent&version=0.19.1 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@5.0.4: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] debug has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=debug&version=2.2.0 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] lodash has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=lodash&version=3.10.1 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN deprecated mailparser@0.6.2: Mailparser versions older than v2.3.0 are deprecated
npm WARN deprecated scmp@0.0.3: scmp v2 uses improved core crypto comparison since Node v6.6.0
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] debug has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=debug&version=2.1.3 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] lodash has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=lodash&version=3.1.0 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@1.11.0: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.0.17: Old versions of Formidable are not compatible with the current Node.js; Upgrade to 1.2.0 or later
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] mime has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=mime&version=1.3.4 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] mime has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=mime&version=1.2.11 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] debug has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=debug&version=1.0.5 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] adm-zip has the following vulnerability: 1 high. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=adm-zip&version=0.2.1 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] request has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=request&version=2.36.0 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@0.0.24: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN deprecated mimelib@0.3.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] ms has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=ms&version=0.7.0 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN deprecated mailcomposer@2.1.0: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] lodash has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=lodash&version=3.9.3 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] semver has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=semver&version=1.1.4 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] qs has the following vulnerabilities: 2 high. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=qs&version=0.6.6 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] hawk has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=hawk&version=1.0.0 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] hoek has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=hoek&version=2.16.3 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@2.0.5: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated boom@2.10.1: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated buildmail@2.0.0: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] lodash has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=lodash&version=2.4.2 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated mimelib@0.2.14: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] moment has the following vulnerabilities: 1 moderate, 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=moment&version=1.7.0 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] hoek has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=hoek&version=0.9.1 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@0.9.1: The major version is no longer supported. Please update to 4.x or newer
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] lodash has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=lodash&version=1.0.2 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-12-04T09_50_38_320Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm i   && apk del .gyp  && mv /var/app/node_modules /node_modules   && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* COPY . .' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Usually image dont get a name when build has an error. Are you sure build successfully finished?

Comment: I just took a better look I thought because it took me back to the console that everything worked but I added on the post the output i get before it returns me to the console it does seem like i am getting an error and its not completing the build

Comment: I added my dockerfile as well

Comment: I just try without the lines and I get a world of errors, it does seems to be going further the errors are allot of this is deprecated errors and at the end it does say npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.  So maybe it does need git, but I think allot of these errors I would get even with git, should I post all the error message?

Comment: Is there an error in the syntax of RUN apk install git because I split that section into various RUN commands and apk install git gives me an error and I get a bunch of syntax help: Step 5/13 : RUN apk install git
 ---> Running in 7113e0bc2ef9
apk-tools 2.7.5, compiled for x86_64.

usage: apk COMMAND [-h|--help] [-p|-         ,etc

Comment: @Jack So git is required for npm install. Use this to install git ```RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
  && apk add --no-cache git \
  && npm i \ ...(rest commands)``` . If this fixes the issue let me know so I provide it as answer and remove comments.

Comment: @leopal thanks man that definitely gets me past a few steps, but then it gets stuck at the next step RUN apk del .gyp and gives Step 9/15 : RUN apk del .gyp
 ---> Running in a9462741638d
The command '/bin/sh -c apk del .gyp' returned a non-zero code: 1, any ideas?

Comment: @Jack It's related to the `npm install` maybe. I am not aware of it but can you try building without this command?

Comment: Yup I removed this and also the RUN mv /var/app/node_modules /node_modules  and I was able to get it to build succesfully at last! But i am unsure if some of that might be needed what do you think??? BTW do you want to put an answer so I can check it for you?

Comment: @Jack I am not sure if you should remove `RUN mv /var/app/node_modules /node_modules` command as `node_modules` are probably needed at runtime. Try to process a container from the built image and see if it is working.

Comment: Hi I thought I answered yesterday you are right I was able to build it with the `RUN mv /var/app/node_modules /node_modules` command as well, so I basically built it with everythin now exept the `apk del .gyt` which I am totaly fine with, Thank you very much @leopal would you like to put an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing from comments:

`RUN apk install git` will fail for sure as there is no `install` applet in `apk` tool.

Instead of `install` use `add` applet to install `git` after performing a system update in the build container.

[`Apk` related info](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management)

So the git installation section in your Dockerfile should look like this:

```
    ...
    RUN apk update 
    && apk upgrade \ 
    && apk add --no-cache git \
    ...
```

Comment: I am stuck now after the build running the docker image, can you take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632800/having-trouble-running-a-docker-image-quorra-not-found