# Having trouble running a docker image 'quorra not found'

Tags: docker, dockerfile, quorrajs

After allot of ado I was able to build my dockerimage, but when I try and run it I get the following error:

```
$ docker run swipeimage

> uswipe-merchant@0.0.1 dev /var/app
> NODE_ENV=development quorra ride --watch --env development

sh: quorra: not found


npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! uswipe-merchant@0.0.1 dev: `NODE_ENV=development quorra ride --watch --env development`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the uswipe-merchant@0.0.1 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-12-05T10_01_14_455Z-debug.log
```

I tried adding `RUN npm install quorra`to my docker file to make sure quorra is installed but still get an error.

Comment: try using docker exec for getting terminal and check if the quorra is available in the default PATH

Comment: Got the terminal open how do I check what is available on the default path?

Comment: try which quorra or 
type -a quorra if it's there it'll show if missing find it and add it in env

Comment: seems to be installed when I run `quorra -v` I get `Quorra CLI version: 1.0.0`

Comment: ok now try docker exec -ti <container-name> quorra -v

Comment: There dont seem to be any container running `$ docker exec -ti sleepy_leavitt quorra -v`
`Error response from daemon: Container 646138d8a3bfa8d1649a49bda1a9076037a61ffce392068f5c67a032391059f3 is not running`So I check for the last one and run it `$ docker container start sleepy_leavitt` and it prints out
`sleepy_leavitt` but then I just get the command line again and if I try the exec command it tells me its not running again.

Comment: Can you debug the docker build process, like try adding some run instructions after workdir to check if it's in the path. or update the CMD/ENTRYPOINT to jus the name of command you can execute to check the version like CMD quorra -v check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it, I was looking at the quorra docs, and I changed

```
RUN npm install quorra
```

to

```
RUN npm install -g quorra-cli
```

Now it works!!!

Thanks All